# How to control TranslateAnimation slip direction？

Tags: android, translate-animation

```
showaction = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
             Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
             -1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f);
             showaction.setDuration(500);
```

This method parameters effect is vertical downward slide, now I want to change it from left to right slide. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
showaction = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -1.0f,
             Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
             0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f);
             showaction.setDuration(500);
```

From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html#TranslateAnimation%28int,%20float,%20int,%20float,%20int,%20float,%20int,%20float%29).